# keep the keyboard open on click outside of the keyboard area, javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events, mobile-browser

Keyboard opens on focus of an input.

and there is a button on the page which basically mute/unmute the app.

while keyboard is opened when I clicked the Button the keyboard got dismissed,

I don't want the keyboard to get dismissed on Button click,

I tried `e.stopPropagation)` on Button click, and keyboard still got dismissed.

Is it possible to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a pure javascript solution.
You have to listen for the blur event on the input field. When ever the input field is blurred, immediately call the focus function. This will bring back the focus on to the input field.

Here the input field is given the id `input`

Javascript:

```
var t = document.getElementById("input");
t.addEventListener("blur", (e)=>{
    t.focus()
})
```

The only way to close the keyboard is to press the back button. Pressing anywhere else on the screen wont close the keyboard.